# How to check if a ResultSet of an AJAX call using JQuery has value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am Using iQuery to make AJAX Calls to the server and return a set of values. The Values returned are dynamic. The Result count being dynamic I am not able to look the result set and assign values to HTML Elements to show in Web Page.

Kindly advice how I could look if there is a value in the result set and use the same in my system. The Maximum count in result set is 16 and i have manually assigned values in the Script.

*Calling the AJAX Method in the document ready of my Web Page.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CallAJAX('../Forms/Send.aspx/refreshDash', '', 'FillMethod', 'FillMethodE');
});
```

*AJAX Call Definition*

```
function CallAJAX(ServerMethod, Parameters, SuccessMethod, ErrorMethod) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ServerMethod,
        data: Parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            Error = xhr; Result.d.ResultSet[0].TRCOUNT
            eval(ErrorMethod + "()");
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            Result = msg;
            var rr = SuccessMethod + "();";
            eval(rr);
        }
    });
}
```

*Using Two jQuery Functions to Show Details and prompt Message when error is Raised. Note Error Function is not Shown.*

```
function FillMethod() {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(Result.d.ResultSet)) {

    }
    else {

        $('[id$=lblCode1]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[0].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot1]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[0].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode2]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[1].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot2]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[1].TRCOUNT);


        $('[id$=lblCode3]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[2].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot3]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[2].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode4]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[3].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot4]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[3].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode5]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[4].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot5]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[4].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode6]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[5].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot6]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[5].TRCOUNT);


        $('[id$=lblCode7]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[6].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot7]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[6].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode8]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[7].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot8]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[7].TRCOUNT);


        $('[id$=lblCode9]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[8].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot9]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[8].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode10]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[9].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot10]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[9].TRCOUNT);


        $('[id$=lblCode11]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[10].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot11]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[10].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode12]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[11].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot12]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[11].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode13]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[12].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot13]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[12].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode14]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[13].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot14]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[13].TRCOUNT);


        $('[id$=lblCode15]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[14].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot15]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[14].TRCOUNT);

        $('[id$=lblCode16]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[15].DASH_NAME);
        $('[id$=lblNot16]').html(Result.d.ResultSet[15].TRCOUNT);
    }
};
function FillMethodE() {


}
```

Issue is being raised in the FillMethod function when only Result.d.ResultSet[0].DASH_NAME has a valid value and the following indexes does not have any values. 
**NOTE:** Results are returned in pairs, if DASH_NAME is available then TRCOUNT will also be available for the same index.

[image: Dynamic Result 1]
[image: Dynamic Result 2]

All I need to do is irrespective of the result count i need to display in the labels in order values from the result set dynamically. Here are are two sets of result sets which could be obtained.

Comment: For starters, why are you using `eval()`? This is the devil itself. Never user it.

Comment: secondly, why don't you use a loop in your `FillMethod` function?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  What's wrong with the results being dynamic?  If the results are an array then you can simply loop over that array.  And, to second another user's question, why on earth are you using `eval` instead of just invoking the function directly?

Comment: @MelanciaUK eval()  I did not understand.

Comment: @Dilip: You use `eval()` here: `eval(ErrorMethod + "()");`.  Why?  Why can't you just use this?: `ErrorMethod();`

Comment: @Jerodev Frankly I couldn't implement one. I am a real starter in this jQuery. Yes this is wrong method I had followed but since the maximum count was fixed I just assigned each into labels.

Comment: @Dilip: Are you just asking how to implement loops in JavaScript?  They're really, *really* similar to other languages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @David The error is not being generated by using the eval() method. The issue is being generated in the FillMethod() Function.

Comment: @Dilip: The conversation about the use of `eval()` is parallel to the question being asked.  I realize that the immediate problem isn't the use of `eval()`, but what we're trying to tell you is that you *probably* shouldn't be using `eval()` in this case anyway.  It's not necessary, error-prone, and only going to make debugging this more difficult for you.  As for the actual issue... Again, are you just asking how to *write a loop*?

Comment: @David Understood, will remove eval(). The loop first I couldn't implement one. After referring to the link I implemented one but the issue is the order of value assignment is getting changed and unable to stick to the design location where i want the result set to be in

Comment: @Dilip: That description isn't very clear.  Can you elaborate more in the question?

Comment: @David When i Tried a loop, when i=1 the result set is going to 1 but when the query is returning value in the count say 7, and result sets 1-6 and 8-16 are nulls the value is still going to labels lblCode7 and lblNot7. I want it to go to the lblCode1 and lblNot7 itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62187/discussion-between-dilip-and-david).

Comment: @Dilip: Nobody here can help you debug code you haven't shown with data you haven't shown.  Please update the question to include *what you've tried*, a sample of the *runtime data*, and a *specific description* of the problem.  I'm afraid your run-on sentences are making for very vague and unclear descriptions.

Comment: @David I have posted couple of two possible result sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's still really, *really* unclear what the specific problem is (and the sample result sets you posted don't provide any clarity on why you can't simply loop over them), but I'm willing to take a guess...

Is the problem that you're trying to write a *dynamic* set of results to a *static* set of placeholders for the output?

If that's the case, don't make the placeholders static.  Just keep an empty space where you want the results to show and when you have the results, write them to that part of the page.  You don't *need* HTML elements in place already, you can create them dynamically.  For example:

```
success: function (msg) {
    // let's assume msg is an array of data
    for(var i = 0; i < msg.lengh; i++) {
        $('#output').append(
            '<div>' + msg[i].DASH_NAME + ' - ' + msg[i].DASHSTATUS + '</div>'
        );
    }
}
```

So if your `#output` is just a `div`, the result would look like this:

```
<div id="output">
    <div>SEND CONFIRMED - 1</div>
    <div>RECV HO RESPONDED - 4</div>
    <div>RECV HO PAID - 3</div>
    <!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

How you define and style that markup is entirely up to you, of course.  The point is that you can create the markup on the fly from your JavaScript code, so it can be created dynamically based on the results from the AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really need to work on how I am conveying things, The issue has been resolved simply by adding a loop in the code. The method I had followed was a really bad practice.

Comment: @Dilip: Glad I could finally help :)  As a general word of advice, if you're going to be doing more and more JavaScript work then you'll find it's best to let go of the ASP.NET WebForms control structures.  I recommend adopting ASP.NET MVC instead and taking advantage of the more granular control over the markup and client-side code that it offers.  You can achieve that same control in WebForms, it's just a bit clunkier.

Comment: I would really like to take a bit of help in doing so. Could you please provide me with a starting point. I am an amateur in the field and trying to do some small small work and gain the knowledge.

Comment: @Dilip: Start with some of the ASP.NET MVC tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc  The main thing is to *forget* WebForms when you're in the context of MVC.  A lot of developers try to use MVC "like they're used to in WebForms" and it never works out.  If you can understand the separation of client-side code and server-side code and understand how HTTP requests work, you'll be ahead of most .NET junior web developers.

Comment: Okeyz. I will give that also a check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Result.d.ResultSet.length > 0) {
for (i = 0; i < Result.d.ResultSet.length; i++) {
  $('[id$=lblCode'+i+']').html(Result.d.ResultSet[i].DASH_NAME);
  $('[id$=lblNot1'+i+']').html(Result.d.ResultSet[i].TRCOUNT);

}
```